# Android App shared links on whatsapp are not clickable

Tags: android, whatsapp

I developed an android app, but upon sharing links from app on Whatsapp, the links are not clickable. If I do copy and paste the same message it becomes clickable.

Any idea why? Is it because app is still in development process?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show code

Comment: @Aym B: It has nothing to do with debug/release signature of app.

Comment: can you show, what link you share.. perhaps there may be some issue..
Coz I tried and its working.
Also share your code here

Answer (score 1):

For security if you dont have a contact registered in your phone, whatsapp not show as a hiperlink. This is to avoid virus, spam, etc.

In example, if you are in a whatsapp group and other person share a link in the group, you will see as hiperlink if you have the phone number registered in your phone.

Comment: This is frustrating! Is there any workaround to this? @AndroidRuntimeException